# Как найти индекс последнего совпадения символа/символов в строке с помощью RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка

```
var str = "5+4-3*5+6-7";
```

Мне нужно найти индекс в строке последнего из арифметических знаков - в данном случае "-".
Нашел только вот это решение:

```
var reg = /.*(\+|-|\*)/g;
var match = reg.exec(str);
var index = reg.lastIndex-1;
```

Есть ли решение проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сразу в регулярном выражении задать поиск последнего вхождения

```
var reg = /([+*-])(?=[^+*-]*$)/;
var index = str.search(reg)
```

[**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qs8p9uro/3/)